# PayPal Mass Payment for my customers. Should I store their credentials?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Imagine that I have an app that allows my users to have a shopping cart. In that, I want them to be able to pay their vendors in bulk for the goods sold at the end of the month - a PayPal Mass Payment.

My challenge is that I need to store their API username, API password, and API signature key in order to initialize the Mass Payment on their behalf. This introduces a lot of security liabilities for me. If someone is able to get at this data, the hacker would have access to all of my users' PayPal money - ouch!! I definitely won't store these values in the database as plain text, but still!

How can I overcome this? Any other suggestions?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Permissions API instead: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/